# Change image within my computer using jquery

Tags: jquery

I needed to take an existing image in my code to switch itself with another image within my computer when the mouse hovers over it and place the old image back when the mouse is not hovering over it.

This is the jQuery code I have for it so far:

```
$('.first-image').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('second-image');    
});
$('.second-image').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('first-image'); 
});
```

I am not sure what to replace `toggleClass` with so that it won't switch images between each other. I don't want both of them to switch images when the mouse hovers over it, I only need one of the images to switch into something else in my computer not have them alternate.

Comment: Post your html code with mentioned images.

Answer (score 0):

first-image is a css class, you can replace it with your own css class.

```
<style>
.myimage{
    background-image: url(nameofmyimage.png);
}
</style>


<script>
$('.first-image').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('myimage');
});
$('.second-image').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('myimage'); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
<style>
.yourfirst-image{
    background-image: url(yourfirstimage.jpeg);
}
.yoursecond-image{
    background-image: url(yoursecondimage.jpeg);
}

</style>
<script>
 $(.first-image).mouseover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass(.yoursecond-image);
    });
    $(.first-image).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass(.yourfirst-image);
    });
</script>
```